# Storing formulas (calculations) historically

Tags: php, mysql, formula, historical-db

I have an application that evaluates user submissions and assigns a point value to each submission based on a variety of formulas (flat rate for all, flat rate for first "x" entries, degrading value for first "x" entries). Formulas are based on the type of submission (the category of the submission is what determines point values and formula used in calculating said values).

The issues is that the customer would like to store these formulas historically, so that for any given record they can view the formula that was used to calculate the point value.

I have a few ideas as to how to achieve this, but none really seem like a good option:

1) Store the formulas in the PHP code and comment out past formulas, making sure to note the effective date range.

2) Create a view each time a formula is changed, and update the code to use the new view. Note effective dates in the view name or in the code.

3) Store the formulas in a formula table giving each a unique id, as well as date effective/retired values.

Is there another, or better way to achieve this? The first two would require a lot of code to be written/changed in the event a formula is updated, and the third requires parsing, and stores formulas in the DB (something I was trying to avoid).

Thoughts?

Comment: I like number 3, but don't actually parse the formulas. Store both the results and the formulas historically.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you solve this? If so you should accept the one that did.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to storing the actual code, then the correct place for this is in a source code manager like [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) (SVN). You can tag a release with a specific formula. This way, whenever you release a new formula, it gets tagged. You can also keep track of any minor changes. This means at any point, you can retrieve an old formula for review.

Comment: Whilst I would never vote against use VCS I don't think this solves the problem here as he suggests the customer needs to view the history and calculations for each record.

Comment: You could still do this, even with a VCS.  It's fairly trivial to query for a specific patch and render that to the customer.  In fact, doing it any other way leaves it open for abuse.  Storing it in a DB, for example, means it can be changed without changing the actual code.  At least with an SCM, his clients can be assured of the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly store the results of the formulae in a history table at the very least. Whether you need to store the formulae themselves or not depends on how many formulae you have and how they vary. Your basic table might look something like this

```
calculation_id
record_id
points
formula_ref
```

If you have, say, 6 fixed formulae of which the active formulae are some combination of these then your "formula_ref" might be a unique string per formula (i.e. "first10"). If your formulae vary more than that, or the values vary (i.e. "first x" might change from "first 5" to "first 10" etc) then you might need a separate table for the formula combinations and link to them from the history table using a foreign key. The same goes if you need to allow dynamic adding/editing of the formulae from the app (via an admin GUI or similar) as opposed to manual changes in the code.

Your schema will also depending on how you intend to use the data. If you are only ever interested in the history per record, the basic schema as above with a text based formula_ref field would probably suffice (with an index on the record_id).

Feel free to post back your specific schema plan for more comment...